# How Do I Trigger An Event on the press of a key in VB?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2012, button

I have an app in visual basic that displays a message box with a text range from A - F upon user integer input in a textbox.

I have a button control on the form that triggers the event, but the user has to press the button every time to get a result, that's cool, but what if I wanted the event triggered by say the `B` key on my keyboard?

I know of a way of assigning the `AcceptButton` property to my button in visual studio 2012 which accepts just the `Enter` key alone. I want the same effect as pressing the button on the press of a key on a keyboard instead. Thanks.

Comment: set KeyPreview to true on the form and then you can process keypresses.  However, it will process **ALL** keypresses so even if they want to type B into a textbox, your MessageBox will pop up

Comment: Oh wow, I didn't think It would conflict with the textbox, can I use special keys like the `Alt`, `Shift`, `Ctrl` keys too?

Comment: yes, but wouldnt it be easier to respond to Enter in the input textbox and treat it as a button click?

Comment: LOL, Yeah I already know how to do that, but I just thought I could learn how to assign a different key instead, for example, the vlc media player app accepts the `Space` button to play media files, I thought it should be possible implementing such in my vb app too.

Comment: yes you can using the form keydown event, BUT it will see all the key presses even when the user really wants to type B into a textbox on the form.  VLC doesnt have to worry about that because there are no textboxes

Comment: Haha.. let's assume my form doesn't have a textbox control, If I decided to create the keydown event, do I have to paste all the statements in my button control's stub as the keydown event generates its own event stub? Also, How do I assign a key to the event?

Comment: use/look at the arguments passed to it, especially `e` it will tell you if the control key is pressed etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the form Keydown event, and check to see if the B key was pressed. If so, display the messagebox.

```
Private Sub Form1_KeyDown(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs) Handles Me.KeyDown
If e.KeyCode = Keys.B Then MsgBox("B key was pressed")
End Sub
```

Comment: Can you type a snippet of what it'd be like in the event stub please?, I'm still very new to vb.

Comment: Sorry, @xpda .. I forgot to ask, how do I pass my button's statements in the keydown event stub?